# Can I infer a type in an abstract class?

Tags: typescript

I would like to see if the return type of a function in an abstract class can be overridden by a child class:

Parent.ts

```
abstract class Parent<T> {
  abstract data: T | T[];

  // Can this return as T or T[] (not T | T[]) depending on implementation of 
  // child?
  getData() {
    return this.data;
  }
}
```

Child.ts

```
class Child extends Parent<Person> {
  data: Person[] = [];
}
```

index.ts

```
const child = new Child();
child.getData() // Can this be returned as Person[] automatically without typecast?
```

I know I can typecast in `index.ts`, but I was wondering if there is a way for TypeScript to automatically infer the type of data.

Comment: You can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/mMRG1W) using polymorphic `this` types.  But why are you using a getter accessor for `getData()`?  Is that a typo?  If so, please fix it. If not, please explain what's going on.

Comment: Thank you! It is not a typo, the getter is mapped to a VueX getter function, and I call the getter to get the state via the getter rather than the store itself.

Comment: You've got an error somewhere in that example code.  Either you should remove the getter accessor or you should make it return a function (like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w6Brvw) maybe).  What you've got now here isn't a [mre] because of that.  It really doesn't look like your question has anything to do with getters versus properties versus methods (given the fact that my comment helped you) so you should probably just remove the accessor in the question.

Comment: Will do, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want a class to dynamically refer to the type of the "current" class instance, which could be a more specific subclass, you can use the [polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) (that is, you use `this` as a type).

In fact, if you inspect the type of `this` inside `getData()`'s implementation, you will see that the compiler infers it to be of type `this`:

```
// this: this
```

But the compiler will often widen `this` to the class type, especially when you access a property; so while the type of `this` is seen as type `this`, the type of `this.data` is seen as type `Parent<T>['data']`, which is `T | T[]`.  Instead, you want `this['data']`, meaning "the type of the `data` property on whatever `this` is".

If you want to prevent that widening of `this['data']` to `Parent<T>['data']`, you can explicitly [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) a new variable of this type:

```
getData() {
    const data: this['data'] = this.data;
    return data;
}
```

Or you can [annotate the return type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#return-type-annotations) of the method:

```
getData(): this['data'] {
    return this.data;
}
```

Or you can [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that the return value is of that type:

```
getData() {
    return this.data as this['data'];
}
```

---

Once you do this, then callers of `getData()` in subclasses will have the more specific type information you care about:

```
interface Person { name: string }

class Child extends Parent<Person> {
    data: Person[] = [];
}

const child = new Child();
child.getData().map(person => person.name); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.2#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgCsKBTAdhADwAqAfAgN4BQCdCokM8CAJsBMAFwIkIA+vANoBdANzVa9AOa4IAEQ7AAFAEoqU+vQD02hBAAWASzA9DJzVqQB7fJDZKzxsEIDk7Tq5EIAvPucAdB7AElb0eBAArlD4Dpyh9AC+klqyCkoATGpOJm7BXhphdBHRseZgQUoJdMmWaYqcAMxqhUUlMf4mlZwMGOV5Sl7VCLWW2gBUaQj1Si00RTZ2iME5Lu6D3n7l3cCWWu2xLT4UwcOJ49qStUaEuFAAZnC4WHdgtlQI+MAAtrg8TDdpCNJCg0BgAMLGZCsBC4AAeEAIrAw2DwhCImFetgo83oKxeUDe+FEvgQogktVgtnssChML8+FwAHcEJCjNC1BJaezWAEZpw1AFvsAAA7KEVY2LHBASwm2AJfX6qahAA)